# Leaflet push GPS position to array onLocationFound and search a squared area around this position

Tags: leaflet, array

So I have this approach of pushing the coordinates of a location to an array:

```
var gpsposition = [],
function onLocationFound(e) { gpsposition.push(e.latlng);}
```

Now I have the following questions:

**Q1:** Currently I receive an *Array [Object]* with coordinates, but I want the coordinates to be pushed in *Array [Array [2]]* format  [image]. How do I achieve that?

**Q2:** Am I right in the assumption that

```
L.map.locate({watch: true})
```

triggers *onLocationFound* constantly, meaning that the updated GPS position will be pushed to the array constantly, hence creating a list of positions, too?

**Q3:** A function should search within a square area around each new GPS position, e.g. 100mx100m, through another array with coordinates in *Array [2]* format. Then, it should assign a colour to all circles within that square. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A1: 
You're receiving an instance of `L.LatLng`. If you want those coordinates as an array, then just:

```
var arr = [ latlng.lng, latlng.lat ];
```

Need an array containing just one element, which is an array of the two coordinates? Easy:

```
var arr = [[ latlng.lng, latlng.lat ]];
```

A2:

That indeed fires `onLocationFound` *as fast as the browser's geolocation logic decides*, and will fire new events.

However, that doesn't add the new location to any array or list. If you want to create such a list, you'll have to manage that yourself.

A3:

Create a new `L.Circle` with a desired radius, call `getBounds()` on it, extract the components of that `L.LatLngBounds` instance to create your array, then do whatever calculations you need.

Comment: A1: I have it that way now `gpsposition.push([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng]);`

A2: The `gpsposition.push()` should fill the variable with new coordinates each time `onLocationFound` is fired, I think.

Comment: Is there any option to set the position update to 1 second?

Comment: No, see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition